# Unimodular solutions of a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a homogeneous system of linear equations with complex coefficients:
$$
Az=0,
$$
$z = (z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n)^T \in \mathbb{C}^n$, matrix $A$ has size $m \times n$.

I'm interested in unimodular solutions of such a system, i.e. with $|z_i|=1$.
Equivalently, $z$ is a unimodular vector of a given subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Are there some general methods to solve this problem?
How to find a numerical solution, if it exists?
Or decide the existence, at least.

Also note, that without loss of generality we can assume that
$$
SA = [~I ~|~ B~] 
$$
for some matrix $S$. This means the problem reduces to finding a unimodular vector with a unimodular image under the action of $-B$.

Comment: Do you have any additional information about the structure of $A$ available?

Comment: Yes, in particular, $A$ is Hermitian (and degenerate), but I don't think it gives something, since we can remove some rows.

Comment: But you don't happen to have sign conditions on the entries of the hermitian matrix? (Maybe something like 'all off-diagonal entries are $\ge 0$'?)

Comment: Actually, the condition $A\ge 0$ gives nothing, since any subspace is the kernel of the corresponding orthogonal projection (onto the orthogonal complement).

Comment: @DanyloY: Please add extra information in comments as an edit to the post, as we want posts to be self-contained. Also, comments are easily overlooked